# Rule to redirect to registration page after adding new product to cart

Tags: rules, ubercart

Rule to redirect to registration page after adding new product to cart. I am using ubercart module for this and working with drupal 7

Comment: It is present in store/cart configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the options is given by default in ubercart. Go to admin->store->configuration->cart 
Please check the attached image for more clarification. [image]